# Testing google analytics code for website

Tags: google-analytics

How google analytics tool used on a website can be tested on desktop/notepad or mobile ?
It is required in the project for tracking number of clicks on save button and for many other similar things.
Someone plsss help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Events for tracking clicks: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Then for example in Firebug you should check if when clicking on button where you set Event tracking there is sent request to Google Analytics.

It will look like: 
/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.6dc&utms=6&utmn=1924265606&utmhn=domain.pl&utmt=event&utme=5(Contact*Show*Phone)...

Answer (score 0):

Try [Analytics Debuger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) to track all Analytics calls